# Win32 C++ PRINTER_INFO_2 attributes

Tags: c++, printing

I'm trying to access the friendly name attribute of the [PRINTER_INFO_2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure. But I simply don't know how to do it in C++.

So the following code returns the names in Hexadecimals...

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD dwNeeded = 0, dwPrintersR = 0, Level = 2;
    PRINTER_INFO_2* prninfo=NULL;
    int retValue = 0;

    //Find required buffer size
    EnumPrinters( PRINTER_ENUM_NAME, NULL, Level, NULL, 0, &dwNeeded, &dwPrintersR );


    prninfo = (PRINTER_INFO_2*) GlobalAlloc(GPTR,dwNeeded);
    EnumPrinters( PRINTER_ENUM_NAME, NULL, Level, (LPBYTE) prninfo, dwNeeded, &dwNeeded, &dwPrintersR );
    cout << "# of printers:" << dwPrintersR << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i<dwPrintersR; i++){
        cout << "Printer Name: " << prninfo[i].pPrinterName << "\n";
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to use PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_FRIENDLY_NAME, but I don't know how to do it.

I'm new to C++ and compiled languages.
Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working except for where it actually tries to print the name to the console window.

It appears you're compiling for Unicode, so the printer name is a wide character string (`whcar_t *`).  There's no overload for `std::ostream::operator<<(wchar_t*)`, so you just end up getting the value of the pointer rather than the string.

You need to convert the wide character string to an "ANSI" string, compiler for ANSI instead of Unicode, or output the name using a function that handles wide character strings.  For example, you could replace the `cout` line with:

```
MessageBox(NULL, prninfo[i].pPrinterName, TEXT("Printer Name"), MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply replace this

> cout << "# of printers:" << dwPrintersR << "\n";

with this

> wcout << L"Printer Name: " << prninfo[i].pPrinterName << L"\n";

Tested. It worked.